# change value in json by path in array

Tags: php, json

I have an array like:

```
$arr = ["pages","homepage","welcomeText"];
$newWelcomeText = "Hello there";
```

and JSON which looks like:

```
{
  lang: "en",
  something: [0, 1, 33],
  pages: {
    homepage: {
      welcomeText: "Hello!",
      subHeaiding: "have a nice day"
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to find a way how to replace the "welcomeText" with a new value.
I tried something like:

```
public function findAndReplace ($path, $obj, $data, $index = 0) {
        if($index + 1 == sizeof($path)) {
            if(!is_array($obj)) {
                $obj = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
            }
            $obj[$path[$index]] = $data;
            return $obj;
        }
        return $this->findAndReplace($path, $obj, $data, $index + 1);
    }
```

I never know how the path will look like so I need some kind of function that receives an array and this object as a parameter and returns a modified object.

Comment: Do you want to replace the key `welcomeText`, or simply its value?

Comment: Simply its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I want to replace a value in an JSON onbject by path given in an array, I ended up with this:

```
$json = '{
  lang: "en",
  something: [0, 1, 33],
  pages: {
    homepage: {
      welcomeText: "Hello!",
      subHeaiding: "have a nice day"
    }
  }
}'
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$path = ["pages","homepage","welcomeText"]
```

Function below takes the object and a path to the key in an array and returns a modified object.

```
function findAndReplace ($obj, $path, $data, $index = 0) {
        if($index + 1 == sizeof($path)) {
            if(!is_array($obj)) {
                $obj = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
            }
            $obj[$path[$index]] = $data;
            return $obj;
        }
        $obj[$path[$index]] = findAndReplaceAndDo($obj[$path[$index]], $path, $data, $index + 1);

        return $obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the `array_walk_recursive` function with some extra bells and whistles to allow referential access to array values.

Create some function `array_walk_recursive_referential` which will allow referential access to each key/value and pass it to your own function that you send in(`$function`):

```
function array_walk_recursive_referential(&$array, $function, $parameters = []) {
    $reference_function = function(&$value, $key, $userdata) {
        $parameters = array_merge([$value], [$key], $userdata[1]);
        $value = call_user_func_array($userdata[0], $parameters);
    };
    array_walk_recursive($array, $reference_function, [$function, $parameters]);
}
```

And use it with your `$arr` data:

```
array_walk_recursive_referential($arr, function($value, $key) {
    if(is_string($key))
    {
        if($key === 'welcomeText')
        {
            $value = 'My New Welcome Text'
        }
    }
    return $value;
});
```

Your `$arr` variable is passed in with a reference so you don't need to re-assign it after function call.

Comment: I was unsuccessful in the implementation. The recursive function walks through all keys in object and it is not necessary, I think. But it gave me an Idea how to solve it.

Comment: @flendry the reason it walks through every key in the object is because of your requirement "I never know how the path will look like".  This will allow you do throw any array at it even if you don't know where `welcomeText` is.